# How can I set a particular network to prefer 5Ghz channels in 17.10?

Tags: networking, 17.10, network-manager, iwlwifi

My laptop has an Intel ac-8260 wireless adapter.

I recently upgraded to 17.10 from 16.04. I recall it being trivial in 16.04 to set network manager to prefer to prefer 5Ghz channels for a specified connection. I can no longer find this option in 17.10. I need to do this since my university network is very congested when connecting to 2.4Ghz channels.

Does anyone know how I can do this in 17.10? Preferably without changing any global settings, I want this for one connection only.

Thank you.